# how to retrieve src attribute with xml pullparser

Tags: android

I'm trying to retreive an image link from an rss xml file. The image link is located in an attribute named src. No matter what I do I get a `nullpointerException` or other errors.

The xml file looks like this:

```
 <item>
            <title><![CDATA[מרואן ברגותי פרסם מאמר מסית ב"גרדיאן" בשיא הפיגועים, וקיבל אזהרה בלבד]]></title>
            <description><![CDATA[<div><a href='http://www.ynet.co.il/articles/0,7340,L-4712918,00.html'><img src='http://images1.ynet.co.il/PicServer3/2013/07/30/4764329/18489290991962183103no.jpg' alt='צילום: AP' title='צילום: AP' border='0' width='100' height='56'></a></div>רב-המרצחים הפלסטיני שעמד מאחורי שורה ארוכה של פיגועי טרור הועמד לדין משמעתי בעקבות מאמר מסית שפרסם ב"גרדיאן" הבריטי בשיא הפיגועים בחודש האחרון. בין היתר כתב כי "לא נחיה עם הכיבוש ולא ניכנע לו"]]></description>
            <link><![CDATA[http://www.ynet.co.il/articles/0,7340,L-4712918,00.html]]></link>
            <pubDate><![CDATA[Sun, 18 Oct 2015 15:38:00 +0300]]></pubDate>
            <guid><![CDATA[http://www.ynet.co.il/articles/0,7340,L-4712918,00.html]]></guid>
            <tags><![CDATA[מרואן ברגותי]]></tags>
        </item>
        <item>
```

My code is:

```
    while(eventype!=XmlPullParser.END_DOCUMENT)
                    {  
                        if(eventype==XmlPullParser.START_TAG)
                        {  
                            tagname=parser.getName();

                            if(item)
                            {
                                if(tagname.equals("title"))
                                        title=true;
                                if(tagname.equals("link"))
                                    link=true;
                                if(tagname.equals("description"))
                                {

                                    while(eventype!=XmlPullParser.START_TAG && tagname.equals("img")==false)
                                          eventype=parser.next();

                                    String imgrext= parser.getText();
                                    Log.i("imag text is",imgrext);
                                    description=true;

                                }

                            }

                            else//not item
                            {
                                if(tagname.equals("item"))
                                    item=true;
                            }
                        }
                        if(eventype==XmlPullParser.END_TAG)
                        {
                            tagname=parser.getName();
                            if(tagname.equals("item"))
                                item=false;
                        }
                        if(eventype==XmlPullParser.TEXT)
                        {

                            if(title)
                            {
                                coteret=parser.getText();
                                coteretfilled=true;
                                title=false;
                            }
                            if(link)
                            {
                               _link=parser.getText();
                                linkfiled=true;
                                link=false;
                            }
                            /*if(description)
                            {

                                String cdata = parser.getText();
                                Log.i("Info", cdata);

                                // result = cdata.substring(cdata.indexOf("<img"), cdata.indexOf("alt"));
                              Log.i("Info", result);
                            //   Log.i("Info", cdata.indexOf("alt")+"");
                                description=false;
                            }
                            */


                            if(coteretfilled && linkfiled)
                            {
                                TitlesVieLinks titlink=new TitlesVieLinks(coteret, _link);  
                                tl.add(titlink);
                                coteretfilled=false;
                                linkfiled=false;
                            }
                        }

                        eventype = parser.next();

                    }//end of while loop
```

I used the `getAttributeCount` but it returns -1

Answer (score 0):

```
if(description)
{
     String srcdata = parser.getText();
     int idxStart = srcdata.indexOf("src=");
     if (idxStart > 0)
     {
         int idxEnd = Math.max(srcdata.indexOf(".jpg"), crcdata.indexOf(".png"));  //returns the greater of 2 int values 
          if (idxEnd > 0)
          {
               result = srcdata.substring(idxStart+5, idxEnd+4);
          }
     }
    else
       result="";

}
```